# Removing spacing between ListView rows using a custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to figure out how to remove spacing between rows in a `ListView` using a custom adaptor that returns an `ImageView` in the `getView()` function.

Visual representation of the issue:
[image]

The `ListView` is currently sitting inside a `RelativeLayout`.

I have tried setting the padding, divider and margins all to 0dp on the `ListView` with no luck. I have also tried setting the padding on each individual `ImageView` item within the `getView()` function - all with no luck.

How do I remove all padding/margins/spacing between the `ListView` rows? I am open to any solution whether Java or XML based.

ListView XML:

> ```
> <ListView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/listView1"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
>     android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
>     android:divider="@null"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>     android:layout_margin="0dp"
>     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
>     />
> ```

Relevant getView() adaptor code

```
#some irrelevant code to load images

viewGroup.setClipToPadding(false);
viewGroup.setPadding(0,0,0,0);


if(view == null){
    ImageView newView = new ImageView(this.context);
    newView.setImageDrawable(img);
    newView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    return newView;
}
else{

    ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable(img);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your adapter code? And the XML for the list item itself?

Comment: Added the getView and ListView XML. There's no other Java code relating to layouts. Need anything else?

Comment: please post your full `getView` and custom layout for your list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to use `setAdjustViewBounds` on the new ImageView.

Example from original code in getView():

```
        if(view == null){
            ImageView newView = new ImageView(this.context);
            newView.setImageDrawable(img);
            newView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            newView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            return newView;
        }
        else{

            ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable(img);
            return view;
        }
```